# Greasemonkey | Автонажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript

Приветствую!

На чужом сайте есть кнопка, которую нужно автоматом нажимать после обновления страницы. Исходный код кнопки:

```
<li>
    <a original-title="" href="javascript:;" class="bump" data-tradeid="25346231" data-tipsy="Bump">
        <div class="icon_bump"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Выполняться скрипт будет в *Greasemonkey* (userscript).
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать или где найти нужную информацию по такой задачке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что один атрибут рандомный, надо было уточнить в условии.
Так, вероятно, сработает:

```js
function load(){
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.bump[data-tipsy="Bump"]'); // Ищем все ссылки с классом "bump" и data-tipsy="Bump", на data-tradeid можно забить, хотя если критично, можно и по нему искать
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(e){ // Проходим все найденные ссылки
    e.click(); // Кликаем!
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load); // Чтобы скрипт сработал после создания элементов в DOM
```

```html
<li>
<a original-title="" href="javascript:" class="bump" data-tradeid="25346231" data-tipsy="Bump">
<div class="icon_bump"></div>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Это действительно работает. И Greasemonkey ведет себя адекватно и как положено.Огромное спасибо!  Немного не в тему, но Подскажите пожалуйста книгу по JS для начала обучения. Знаю в интернете много советов, но вижу вы разбираетесь и скорее подскажите верный вариант. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @mrforester, Любая книга по любому ЯП даст только базовые знания. Их можно взять в почти любой книге, например многие хвалят "JavaScript. Библия пользователя" (странно что не погроммиста...) Дэнни Гудмана.  
Лично я получал основы с сайта, а не книги: http://javascript.ru/
Весьма обширное количество ман и без воды, что всегда бесит в книгах для новичков (сохраните через "Ctrl+S", нажмите сюда... Я, блин, новичок, а не ребёнок с синдромом Дауна!).
Но главное - это практика, с основами дальше "Hello, world" не уйдёшь.
Удачи в обучении!

Answer (score 0):

Eсли без jQuery, то как вариант:

```
// получаем в масcив все элементы с классом bump
var l = document.getElementsByClassName("bump"); 

// .click() для первого елемента в масиве
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    l[i].click();
}
```

Comment: К сожалению он не работает. Я пытался сделать jquery, но страница также его использует и это приводит к конфликту. На странице перестают работать все javascript'ы.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('bump');

for (var i = 0, link;
  (link = links[i]); i++) {
  if (link.getAttribute("data-tradeid") === '25346231') {
    link.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a original-title="" href="javascript:;" class="bump" data-tradeid="25346231" data-tipsy="Bump" onclick='this.innerHTML = "clicked"'>no clicked
<div class="icon_bump"></div>
</a>

  <a original-title="" href="javascript:;" class="bump" data-tradeid="25346232" data-tipsy="Bump" onclick='this.innerHTML = "clicked"'>no clicked
<div class="icon_bump"></div>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: data-tradeid="". Это рандомный атрибут. К сожалению пример не работает даже с data-tradeid="25346231".

Comment: @mrforester, сорри, в FF innerText не пашет )